# delete all in rest.api?

Tags: node.js, postman-collection-runner, rest

How to delete all JSON in MongoDB collections using rest API?

```
router.delete('/:id', async(req, res)=> {

    const delbyid = await persons.deleteOne();
        res.status(200).json(delbyid);
```

})

Comment: in postman its only have delete > localhost:2000/persons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deleteOne and deleteMany methods exist in the Collection class and are used to remove documents from MongoDB.

Use persons.deleteMany({});

Ref. [db.collection.deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/)
[CRUD Operations](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/tutorials/crud/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use remove method with empty criteria, example:

```
   persons.remove({ });
```

Comment: delete('/:id)<-but here having same uri '/:id' to delete all the data?

Comment: Yes, usualy REST use DELETE method for remove operations, for example: DELETE /persons/1 will remove person =1, and DELETE /persons?criteria=xxx will remove all persons which satisfy the criteria. And you can use this without  criteria